# Is it possible to get distance from user location to specific location in background in IOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5

I need to calculate distance from user location to specific location, when the app is in background, and get a local notification based on that.

**Background location tracking is totally possible, and I have already done that, but is it possible to execute a block of code, containing some condition checking and based on that update and get a local notification?**

I am not getting any proper solution. Is there any way to do so?

Can you help me please?

Comment: yes, there is way to do it, because the `location services` can run in the background.

Comment: background location tracking is totally possible, and I have already done that, but is it possible to execute a block of code, containing some condition checking and based on that update and get a local notification?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, you can definitely do that. I'm doing it in an app right now. Use significant location changes, or regions, as previously suggested, to keep the pressure off the users battery as much as possible.

We observe regions (and significant location changes where regions are not supported by the device) then check a few things and fire off a local notification if needs be.

We started with a basic prototype to prove the concept and I highly recommend that approach as a way to get familiar with the location and notification frameworks.

Comment: Hi Michael, background location tracking is totally possible, and I have already done that, but is it possible to execute a block of code, containing some condition checking and based on that update and get a local notification?

Comment: Hey. Yep, all possible. We get the callbacks for location, do some logic checks related to location and also to other device state information then, if the logic dictates it, we register a local notification to fire as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Start with the [Location Awareness Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH2-SW1). Most everything you need to know is in there. (Most things that aren't in there are simply impossible for an AppStore app.) See also Tracking the User's Location in the [iOS App Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW25).

The best tool for what you're describing is likely "Shape-Based Regions." You can basically draw a box on a map and say "when the user enters or leaves this box, let me know." If at all possible, this is the tool you should use. It has the least impact on battery life.

If you absolutely cannot solve the problem any other way, it is legal to request background location delivery with `startUpdatingLocation` (and the appropriate background mode in Info.plist; see the above docs). An app that tracks your route while you hike would be be appropriate for this kind of setup. But you should avoid it if at all possible since it's a major battery drain.

Comment: Hey Rob, background location tracking is totally possible, and I have already done that, but is it possible to execute a block of code, containing some condition checking and based on that update and get a local notification? I have to check my location to be within 200 meters of a bunch of locations(I mean an array) and want to get a notification.

Comment: Look at the Shape-Based Regions that I referenced in the above document. That should do what you're discussing. It's not a local notification; it's just a delegate callback. But that should be exactly what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to update for significant locations in the background: http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-multitasking-background-location/.  Then you will want to create a location notification based on that.

My issue is that I am not sure if you can create a local notification in the background.